# How to select all n element after x element?

Tags: css

I'm trying to style my all span which is after i element but there is something weird i couldn't achieve.I couldn't styling my span element in order of.

here is my code

```css
.header p span:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}

.header p span:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}

.header p span:nth-child(3) {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <p>
    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
    <span>444</span>
    <span>01</span>
    <span>34</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: it counts the number of element from the very first element despite of its tag or class you mention.

Comment: so could i select all span element  by order after <i> i think ?

Comment: The ":nth-child(1)" is the first element, instead of the ":nth-child(0)". So the "i" tag should has the red color, but it is an "i" tag so it stays black. Try "nth-of-type".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either want to use `nth-of-type` or the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

```css
span:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: red;
}

span:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: blue;
}

span:nth-of-type(3) {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <p>
    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
    <span>444</span>
    <span>01</span>
    <span>34</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

```css
span {
  color: green;
}

i ~ span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <p>
    <span>Some span before the `i` tag.</span>
    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
    <span>444</span>
    <span>01</span>
    <span>34</span>
  </p>
  
  <span>Some span elsewhere in the document</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

:nth-child will count the i-element also so you would have to use indexes 2,3 and 4 for it to work as you want. Or you could use [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) if you want to only include the span-elements:

```css
.header p span:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: red;
}

.header p span:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: blue;
}

.header p span:nth-of-type(3) {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <p>
    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
    <span>444</span>
    <span>01</span>
    <span>34</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work, its the i tag that is the issue here

```css
div > span:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}

div > span:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}

div > span:nth-child(3) {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <p>
    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
    <div>
     <span>444</span>
     <span>01</span>
     <span>34</span>
    </div>
  </p>
</div>
```